# Mongoose: "Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to perform a simple search in Mongoose getting all users within a given radius of the querying user. In other words, a user logs in and I want to fetch all the users within 20 miles, not including the querying user.

I'm getting a strange error: `"Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined"` when I'm not even using `forEach`. Even weirder, the query has two parts: `_id` and `loc`, and when I perform each one individually they work, but not together.

My code is below, can anyone help me understand what is going on?

```
app.post("/get_users", (req, res) => {
  console.log("get users"); // 
  console.log("req.body :", req.body);
  const miles = 20;
  const meters = Math.floor(miles * 1609.34);
  const loc = req.body.loc;
  const userId = req.body.userId;
  
  User.find({ loc: {
     $near: {
       $geometry: {
          type: "Point" ,
          coordinates: loc
       },
       $maxDistance: meters,
       $minDistance: 0
     }
   },
   _id: { $ne: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) }
  })
  .then((users) => {
    console.log("users : ", users); // <- not being written to console
    return res.json({ users })
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log("Err  : ", err);
    return res.json({ error: "error" });
  });
});
```

Comment: Not really sure but it should be app.get instead of post. You can also check line number on error - d property 'forEach' of undefined.

Comment: Geometry is expecting a 2-element array for `coordinates:`, what data type is `req.body.loc`?